# Why isn't 或者 written as 或则，similar to 否则?

Tags: word-choice

According to my understanding, the correct use of "或者"(meaning "or"). But the character "者" means a person who specialized in something. Why isn't it "或则" similar to "否则". Since "则" has any meanings. Like: to follow, standard/norm, then, etc. Sorry if this is supposed to be something obvious.

Comment: 或则 is used in old Chinese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [百度百科](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%88%96%E5%88%99/10951004)，`或则` is a valid Chinese word (have similar meaning to `或者`)

> 鲁迅《华盖集·“碰壁”之馀》：“平时憎恶我的却总希望我做一个完人，即使敌手用了卑劣的流言和阴谋，也应该正襟危坐，毫无愤怒，默默地吃苦；**或则**戟指嚼舌，喷血而亡。”参见“或者”。

In the above quoted text, 或则 can be considered as **or else**

`或者` can also mean `somebody` or `someone`:

> 《初刻拍案惊奇》卷二十：“**或者**因一句话上，成就了一家儿夫妇；**或者**因一纸字中，拆散了一世的姻缘。”

Comment: “或者因一句话上，成就了一家儿夫妇；或者因一纸字中，拆散了一世的姻缘。” I don't think 或者here means someone. I think this is a case of ellipsis.  “(someone)或者因一句话上，成就了一家儿夫妇；(someone)或者因一纸字中，拆散了一世的姻缘。” It's quite common in Chinese to omit the subject.

Comment: Nope, if you think this way, then 或者 is meaningless or redundant. You have “或曰” as “someone says”.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, “者” doesn't have to stand for a person.
According to [新华字典](http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/11340.html)， “者” can refer to either someone, like

> 读书者有几。——清·袁枚《黄生借书说》

where 读书者 means a person who reads,

or something, like

> 逝者如斯夫!不舍昼夜。——《论语》

where 逝者 means the passing time, and

> 二者不可得兼。——《孟子·梁惠王上》

where 二者 refers to “these two things mentioned above”.

There's much more examples, where 者 can also stand for "the reason of which", etc.
So, I would consider 或者 as "something alternative" or something likes that.